# What to use in place of webclient in windows 8 metro style app

Tags: c#, windows, httpclient, webclient

In Past, I have developed an app in windows phone, in which I downloaded the json data using the webclient with the syntax "`openreadasync`" and then called the "`openreadcompleted`" event handler. Now I am developing an app for windows 8 metro style but as webclient is not present in visual studio 12 rc I am searching for it's alternative....

I thought of using "`httpclient`" but not able to understand how to download json data as stream in it and then call it's event handler....what event handler should I call?

can you give some example?...I am new to c# so please explain a little thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no event handlers in `HttpClient`. Instead, you call methods like [`GetAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which return `Task`s. To get the result of the `Task`, you can use the new `await` keyword (which also requires you to mark the whole method as `async`).

So, your code might look like:

```
Stream responseStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
```

Comment: i tried this but the problem is how do i call this method.....i want to call this method from OnNavigatedTo method can you give the syntax and explain a little as i don't know much about tasks and how to use it...thanks for replying

Comment: It should be enough to just mark the method as `async` and include the code in it.

Comment: Indeed, what svick says here is true. 
It should indeed be enough to mark the method as `Async` and use the await keyword. I think this msdn blog gives a good example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/04/03/async-in-4-5-worth-the-await.aspx

I used that one to create my first metro style app.
MS has a big amount of examples on their site: 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples

It can come in handy one day.